# IE9, Javascript: Create and append a new element

Tags: javascript, append, element, internet-explorer-9

I'm having some serious trouble getting my code to work in IE9, works fine in Chrome & Firefox but I throws some errors. Here are my 2 functions:

```
function insertHTML(content){
    var body=document.getElementsByTagName('body');
    body[0].appendChild(createElement(content));
 }

function createElement(string){
     var container=document.createElement('div');
     container.innerHTML=string;
     var element=container.firstChild.cloneNode(true);
     return element;
 }
```

I've tried severel methods for this and none seem to work, I'll explain exactly what I need to do...

...I need to create a new element from an html string, the string is sent back from an ajax call so my script will have almost no idea what it contains until it gets it.

I did try using element.innerHTML but this is no good, because if i have one html element (form) on the screen and the user enters data into it, and then when another element is inserted it will wipe all the user-entered data from the first form. I was doing element.innerHTML+=newData;

So basically, I need 2 things:

1) A way to create a new element from an html string.
2) A way to append the element to the document body.

It all needs to work cross-browser and I'm not allowed to use jQuery, also the new element cannot be contained in a div parent item, it has to have the body as its parent.

Thanks very much for your help,

Richard

Answer (score 0):

innerHTML is read write and will destroy anything inside your div. use with extreme care

```
function insertHTML( htmlString ){
    var bodEle = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
    var divEle = createElement("div");
    divEle.innerHTML = htmlString;
    bodEle.appendChild(divEle);
}
```

Comment: sorry this won't do it, the exact error that IE9 gives is: Error: Unable to get value of the property 'cloneNode': object is null or undefined... So the problem is with the createElement function.

Comment: you have a function named createElement() which ... coincidentally ... is the name of a JavaScript function.  try changing the name of your function as that might be creating a problem

Comment: also ... don't use single quotes in your getElementsById("").  use double quotes

Comment: no, still not working, the problem is this 1 line: element=container.firstChild.cloneNode(true); It can't get the clone node function on the container div

Comment: IE <= 9 behaves different than modern browsers when manipulating the `document.body`.  If your script tag happens in `<head>` it will take place before the body has populated. [`cloneNode`](https://caniuse.com/#search=cloneNode) support is unknown for IE, and I don't think it's necessary for this.

Comment: Anyone using IE 9 should upgrade to a modern browser.

Answer (score 0):

> So basically, I need 2 things:
>
> 1. A way to create a new element from an html string.
> 2. A way to append the element to the document body.
>
> It all needs to work cross-browser and I'm not allowed to use jQuery, also the new element cannot be contained in a div parent item, it has to have the body as its parent.

The following was tested in IE8

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
var divBefore = document.createElement('div');
var divAfter = document.createElement('div');
var htmlBefore = '<span><span style="font-weight: bold">This bold text</span> was added before</span>';
var htmlAfter = '<span><span style="font-weight: bold">This bold text</span> was added after</span>';

divBefore.innerHTML = htmlBefore;
divAfter.innerHTML = htmlAfter;

document.body.appendChild(divBefore);

setTimeout(function() {
    document.body.appendChild(divAfter);
}, 0);

</script>
<div>This content was here first</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Renders**

```
This bold text was added before
This content was here first
This bold text was added after
```

https://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/7e166dc72b636d3dffdd3739a19ff8956e9cea96

---

In the above example, if you don't need to be able to prepend to the body (i.e. insert content before what already exists), then simply place the script tag after the original content and don't use `setTimeout`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div>This content was here first</div>
<script>
var divAfter = document.createElement('div');
var htmlAfter = '<span><span style="font-weight: bold">This bold text</span> was added after</span>';

divAfter.innerHTML = htmlAfter;

document.body.appendChild(divAfter);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```